# How to extract every nth element of a list

Tags: r

I have a list containing objects of different sizes. Some are massive matrices, others are singular values. How can I extract just the matrices from the list and put them into their own list? Also, every matrix is stored in the 1st position of 7 (1,8,15,22, etc).

Comment: Do you need something like: `new_list <- my_list[0:3 * 7 + 1]`? Or how exactly is your list structured?

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
new_list <- lst1[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(1, 6))]
```

It works as a recycling index

```
(1:30)[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(1, 6))]
[1]  1  8 15 22 29
```